# C Code linking to C++ in CLion not working

Tags: c++, c, clion

I know there are huge amount of posts, but going through lots of them i found nothing that worked.

I want to include some .h and .c files into my C++ file.

Clicking into the method in CLion it redirects me to that foo.h file, but in the end it's not working with following message:

**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fooFct", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64**

**foo.h**

```
 void fooFct();
```

**foo.c**

```
void fooFct(){
    /* do some stuff here */
 }
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    #include "clibraryFolder/header/foo.h"
}

int main() {
    fooFct();
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
 project(newcsample)

 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

 set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
 add_executable(newcsample ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

But I don't want to include the C files in the CMakeFiles.txt. Is there another way doing this than by editing the CMakeFiles?

Comment: What does your `CMakeLists.txt` file look like? Does it list `foo.c` in the source list?

Comment: you are declaring the fooFct() function, but you are not linking in its definition: the latter should be in the object file created for foo.c, are you linking it as well?

Comment: you mean something like `gcc -c Cfile.c`, `gcc -shared -o libCfile.so cFile.o`,  `c++ -L/somehwere -Wall main.cpp -o main -lCfile`? Nope, I wanted to fully get it done by CLion. Or isn't it possible?

Answer (score 4):

make the following changes in your `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
 project(newcsample)

 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

 set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp foo.c) #all .cpp files and .c files here
 add_executable(newcsample ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

and if the #include you can specify only the current directory if the .h file is there.